# Contpy error in VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, integrated-terminal-window

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open '\.\pipe\conpty-5521331.815324881-in').

I keep getting this error and not sure how to fix it. I've tried a bunch of different things. It happens each time I try to open new integrated terminal in vscode. Command prompt works fine outside of vscode and I made sure to close it while using vscode.

VS Code Version: 1.78.2 user setup
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Comment: here's a google search query you can use to find related github issues: `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open" "conpty"`. I got 9 search results that look like good matches. The two most recent are https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180268 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177965. Those issue tickets needed more info to diagnose the problem. Please see the recommended actions in those tickets to get tips on how to improve your question post.

Comment: oh hello there! https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182514